# How to invoke an Objective-C block obtained at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to write a mock of `HKHealthStore`. In the stubbed `executeQuery:` I need to call the [result handler block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSampleQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKSampleQuery/initWithSampleType:predicate:limit:sortDescriptors:resultsHandler:) of a `HKSampleQuery` instance passed to it. The block is private so I need to get it at runtime. This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)executeQuery:(HKQuery *)query {
    NSAssert([query isKindOfClass:HKSampleQuery.class], @"Mock executeQuery: not implemented yet for other query types than HKSampleQuery");

    HKSampleQuery *sampleQuery = (HKSampleQuery *)query;
    NSMutableArray<HKObject *> *queryResults = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (HKObject *o in self.storedObjects) {
        if ([sampleQuery.predicate evaluateWithObject:o]) {
            [queryResults addObject:o];
        }
    }

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"resultHandler");
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(HKSampleQuery.class, selector);
    IMP imp = method_getImplementation(m);
    typedef void(*resultHandler_t)(id, SEL, void(^)(HKQuery*, NSArray*, NSError*));
    resultHandler_t f = (resultHandler_t)imp;

    // here, I need to invoke the result handler block with sampleQuery, queryResults and nil as arguments
}
```

Note the selector name is "resultHandler" even though the parameter of the initializer of `HKSampleQuery` is called "resultsHandler".

Is there any way to invoke the block with appropriate arguments?

Comment: How about `f(sampleQuery, queryResults, nil);`

Comment: That doesn't work because of the resultHandler_t typedef, which, honestly, I'm also not sure if I have right.

I tried two variants, none of them worked:

1) What you suggested. It compiled, but the block did not get called:
`typedef void(*resultHandler_t)(HKQuery*, NSArray*, NSError*));
resultHandler_t f = (resultHandler_t)imp;
f(sampleQuery, queryResults, nil);`

2) With a different typedef, this didn't compile:
`typedef void(*resultHandler_t)(id, SEL, void(^)(HKQuery*, NSArray*, NSError*));
resultHandler_t f = (resultHandler_t)imp;
f(sampleQuery, selector, sampleQuery, queryResults, nil);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing what you think you are doing. You are getting the implementation of the method `resultHandler` (the getter method of the property `resultHandler`). The block you want is the *value* of the property `resultHandler`, which is the *return value* of running the getter method. In other words, you need to run the getter and get the result, not get the getter itself.

Simplest way to call the method and get the return value (since in this case the return value is a regular object pointer type) would be

```
typedef void (^resultHandler_t)(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error);
resultHandler_t f = [sampleQuery performSelector:@selector(resultHandler)];
f(sampleQuery, queryResults, nil);
```

Alternately, if you declare (but not implement) the instance method or property `resultHandler` in a dummy category of `HKSampleQuery`, you can then access the property directly like `resultHandler_t f = sampleQuery.resultHandler;`